# Flask- MySQL: how to handle payload to Insert to DB?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to insert a payload to the DB, and I have this code:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        credentials = jsonify(data)
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO User (username, fb_id, auth_token, date_joined)
                VALUES (%(username)s, %(fb_id)s, %(auth_token)s, %(date_joined)s''',
                    credentials) 
    return "ok"
```

**This is the sample JSON that I am trying to test out on Postman:**

```
{
  "username": "edjones",
  "fb_id": "aklsjdla123",
  "auth_token": "alksdjaks",
  "date_joined": 12309201910
}
```

**This is the error I get on Postman:**

```
    args = tuple(map(db.literal, args))
TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration
```

What is the correct way to go about handling the payload?

Comment: Did you accidentally created map function in your python file. ? Also please include full traceback that helps to solve the problem quickly.

Comment: Please include the full traceback in debugging questions. The string repr of the exception is almost useless on its own in this case. For example it is unclear which line in your code raises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Request.get_json()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.get_json) returns the *parsed* json body, and [`jsonify()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.json.jsonify) *serializes* data to JSON and wraps it in a Response. The `execute()` method of a cursor expects either a sequence or a map of arguments as the second argument, but you pass it a Response. Drop the call to `jsonify()`:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    credentials = request.get_json()
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO User (username, fb_id, auth_token, date_joined)
                VALUES (%(username)s, %(fb_id)s, %(auth_token)s, %(date_joined)s''',
                credentials) 
    return "ok"
```

Since you've already limited the accepted methods to POST in the [`route()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.route) decorator, the if-guard should be redundant.